# Wie kann ich komplizierte Verhältnisse vereinfachen?

Tags: word-usage, usage, idiom, noun

Beispiel:

> Wenn also jemand, der Pizza mag einen anderen, der Pizza nicht mag,
>   dazu auffordert, etwas anderes als Pizza zu essen, also das, was ein
>   anderer tut, der neulich eine Werbeagentur gegründet hat, dann muß ja
>   der, der die Pizza nicht mag, nein der von der Werbeagentur mag Pizza
>   auch nicht, stattdessen...

Man weiß also zum Schluß gar nicht mehr, wer womit wann gemeint ist. Wie kann ich so formulieren, daß man mir folgen kann?

Comment: Der Satz ist nicht kompliziert, sondern einfach unlogisch. Diese Schlussfolgerung "also das, was ein anderer tut," passt nicht zum ersten Teil des Satzes.

Comment: Was hat die Werbeagentur damit zu tun? Der Einschub "nein der von der Werbeagentur mag Pizza auch nicht" sollte besser in Klammern stehen oder mit nem em-Dash abgetrennt sein.

Comment: Und wo ist das Problem, wenn jemand der keine Pizza mag dazu aufgefordert wird, etwas anderes als Pizza zu essen?

Comment: Wenn also A B dazu auffordert C zu essen, also das, was D tut .... hä?

Comment: Der Satz ist weder komplett, noch konsistent und vom Inhalt selbstwidersprüchlich. Da ist nichts zu retten.

Answer (score 2):

Ich glaube, um dir mit deiner Frage am Besten helfen zu können, müssen wir verstehen, worauf du hinaus willst.

Der erste Schritt ist, den "Hauptgedanken" in deiner Aussage zu identifizieren. Zum Beispiel: "A fordert B auf, keine Pizza mehr zu essen". Danach kannst du Schritt für Schritt die Nebensätze beifügen. Damit bleibt dein Satz logisch nachvollziehbar.

Comment: Oder vielleicht einfach auf so manch einen Nebensatz verzichten. Es lebe der Punkt.

Comment: Es geht um komplizierte Verhältnisse mit mehreren Personen. Um Darstellungen, in denen Konstruktionen wie "sagt es einem, der..." oder "wenn man es jemandem mitteilt, der..." kaum vorkommen, in anderen Worten, Ersatz für diffuse Personenbezeichnungen. In Jura habe ich eine interessante Methode kennengelernt, die aber leicht künstlich wirkt: "A sagt, daß er B vertraut habe. B dagegen..." als Ersatz für "A sagt zu einem, daß er ihm vertraut. Der sagt dagegen, daß..."

Comment: Hmmm, haarscharf an einem Kommentar, der sich mehr Klarheit in der Frage wünscht …